# In any network, what is the preferred, community accepted way to document a follow up or final result of a chosen answer?

Tags: support

For a lot of my questions, there may be more than one answer. I typically respond in comments what happened, but what is the community's preferred method of documenting the final result of something? Should I append to that answer directly or should I post a follow up section in the original question. I'd love to able to document *why* I choose this answer as opposed to another similar one.

Comment: Can you give an example?   What do you mean by "final result"?  Normally your first choice should be to use the "accept" and upvote/downvote buttons; can you explain more about the situation and how/why those are inadequate?  That seems important to judge how to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

Explanation on why a particular answer is most useful to you (and most likely future users) is by commenting under the answer. It might explain to other users what particular point was most useful.

For commentary, never use your question or one of the answers, comments are for comments.

Comment: But what about the final outcome or reporting back on the end result